# How to recursively sum up multiple children properties to it parent property in TreeTable using javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, lodash

let's take this json model as an example

```
{
  "ResourceList": [
    {
      "PlannedWork": 20,
      "ActualWork": 10,
      "RemainingWork": 5
    },
    {
      "PlannedWork": 2,
      "ActualWork": 3,
      "RemainingWork": 4
    },
    {
      "PlannedWork": 20,
      "ActualWork": 20,
      "RemainingWork": 20
    }
  ],
  "childrens": [
    {
      "ResourceList": [
        {
          "PlannedWork": 20,
          "ActualWork": 20,
          "RemainingWork": 5
        }
      ],
      "childrens": [
        {
          "ResourceList": [
            {
              "PlannedWork": 20,
              "ActualWork": 20,
              "RemainingWork": 25
            }
          ],
          "childrens": [
            {
              "ResourceList": [],
              "childrens": [],
              "TaskID": "SubTask3",
              "TaskPlannedWork": 0,
          "TaskActualWork": 0,
          "TaskRemainingWork": 0
            }
          ],
          "TaskID": "SubTask2",
          "TaskPlannedWork": 0,
          "TaskActualWork": 0,
          "TaskRemainingWork": 0
        }
      ],
      "TaskID": "SubTask1",
      "TaskPlannedWork": 0,
      "TaskActualWork": 0,
      "TaskRemainingWork": 0
    }
  ],
  "TaskID": "Task1",
  "TaskPlannedWork": 0,
  "TaskActualWork": 0,
  "TaskRemainingWork": 0
}
```

I would like to sum up the **PlannedWork**, **ActualWork** and **RemainingWork** of each resource element in the Resource list array and add it to the correspondent task

The desired output is something similar to this :

```
{
  "ResourceList": [
    {
      "PlannedWork": 20,
      "ActualWork": 10,
      "RemainingWork": 5
    },
    {
      "PlannedWork": 2,
      "ActualWork": 3,
      "RemainingWork": 4
    },
    {
      "PlannedWork": 20,
      "ActualWork": 20,
      "RemainingWork": 20
    }
  ],
  "childrens": [
    {
      "ResourceList": [
        {
          "PlannedWork": 20,
          "ActualWork": 20,
          "RemainingWork": 5
        }
      ],
      "childrens": [
        {
          "ResourceList": [
            {
              "PlannedWork": 20,
              "ActualWork": 20,
              "RemainingWork": 25
            }
          ],
          "childrens": [
            {
              "ResourceList": [],
              "childrens": [],
              "TaskID": "SubTask3",
              "TaskPlannedWork": 20,
              "TaskActualWork": 40,
              "TaskRemainingWork": 29
            }
          ],
          "TaskID": "SubTask2",
          "TaskPlannedWork": 40,
          "TaskActualWork": 60,
          "TaskRemainingWork": 49
        }
      ],
      "TaskID": "SubTask1",
      "TaskPlannedWork": 42,
      "TaskActualWork": 63,
      "TaskRemainingWork": 53
    }
  ],
  "TaskID": "Task1",
  "TaskPlannedWork": 62,
  "TaskActualWork": 73,
  "TaskRemainingWork": 59
}
```

Using a recursive function and using lodash library , so far I came up with this :

I came up with this so far

```
sumTreeElement: function (element, parent) {
            if (element.childrens != null) {
                parent.TaskPlannedWork= _.sumBy(element.ResourceList, function (o) {
                    return Number(o.PlannedWork);
                });
                parent.TaskActualWork= _.sumBy(element.ResourceList, function (o) {
                    return Number(o.ActualWork);
                });
                parent.TaskRemainingWork= _.sumBy(element.ResourceList, function (o) {
                    return Number(o.RemainingWork);
                });
                this.sumTreeElement(element, parent);

            }

        },
```

However I'm a little bit lost and confused due to the fact that recursive functions aren't my strong side , I would like some help

Thank you in advance

Comment: What about your function doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up making my own logic, with the following steps

1. Flatten the Tree Table nodes
2. Group them by their Parent UUID
3. Loop right as to find the parent
4. Sum the desired Property
5. UnFlatten my array so it become a tree table again :)

P.S: I've used lodash 
Works like a charm

```
const filtredProjects = _.filter(projectArray, function (projectt) {
                return projectt.Tasks.length > 1;
            });
            _.forEach(filtredProjects, function (pr) {
                const childrenTasks = _.filter(pr.ProjectTaskList, function (pTask) {
                    return pTask.ParentTaskUUID;
                });
                var filtredProjectsClone =  _.cloneDeep(childrenTasks);

                var childrens = _.groupBy(filtredProjectsClone, function (num) {
                    return num.ParentTaskUUID;
                });
                _(childrens).forEachRight(function (projectTask) {
                    var sumPlannedWorkQuantity = _.sumBy(projectTask, function (o) {
                        return Number(o.PlannedWorkQuantity);
                    });
                    var sumRemainingWorkQuantity = _.sumBy(projectTask, function (o) {
                        return Number(o.RemainingWorkQuantity);
                    });
                    var sumTotalActualWorkQuantity = _.sumBy(projectTask, function (o) {
                        return Number(o.TotalActualWorkQuantity);
                    });
                    var parentTask = _.find(filtredProjectsClone, function (partTask) {
                        return partTask.UUID === projectTask[0].ParentTaskUUID;
                    });

                    if (parentTask) {
                        parentTask.PlannedWorkQuantity = Number(parentTask.PlannedWorkQuantity) + Number(sumPlannedWorkQuantity);
                        parentTask.RemainingWorkQuantity = Number(parentTask.RemainingWorkQuantity) + Number(sumRemainingWorkQuantity);
                        parentTask.TotalActualWorkQuantity = Number(parentTask.TotalActualWorkQuantity) + Number(sumTotalActualWorkQuantity);
                    }
                });
                var unflattenTasks = that.unflatten(filtredProjectsClone, pr.UUID);

                _.remove(pr.Tasks, function (taskToRemove) {
                    return taskToRemove.ParentTaskUUID;
                });

                _.forEach(unflattenTasks, function (unflatTask) {
                    pr.Tasks.push(unflatTask);
                });
```